# How to print pdf from a function

Tags: r

I have a series of tables and graphs that are produced from a list in R. I would like to create a pdf for each iteration of the list. I have tried simply using pdf() within the function but I get the error that too many graphic devices are open. How can I do this (and name the files according to the list element name?

So far I have tried:

```
ReportPDF<-function(x){
pdf(paste(name(x),"~\\Myfile.pdf")
tb<-table(x$acolumn)
print(fb)
}

lapply(mylist,ReportPDF)
```

I cant quite work out how to attach the name of the list element to the filename and I'm not even sure this is the best way to create a pdf from lapply

Comment: Try adding `dev.off()` to the function at the end.

Comment: @ytk. I did that. Same error though

Comment: I might use a `for` loop with this and wrap the loop in `pdf` and `dev.off` to get a single file, or put that inside the loop to get multiple files.

Comment: I'd have a look at `knitr` package (https://yihui.name/knitr/). I think your approach won't work, as `pdf()` is a graphics device, you can not include any output in it.

Answer (score 4):

Can you clean some of this up?
Please give a more specific example of the object you're passing to ReportPDF(), I would expect a plot object, rather than what appears to be a data frame that you are selecting a column from.
The function example has some errors too, did you mean this?

```
ReportPDF<-function(x){
pdf(paste(names(x),"Myfile.pdf"))
tb<-table(x$acolumn)
print(tb)
dev.off()
}

lapply(mylist,ReportPDF)
```

I believe I've done something similar before and can update this answer when I get the other information.

Here's an update making some assumptions about your objects. It uses a `for` loop as lmo suggests, but I think a more elegant method must exist. I'm using the `for` loop because lapply passes the object within each element of the list, with no reference to name of the element in the list -- which is what you need to name the files individually. Note the difference between calling `mylist[i]` and `mylist[[i]]`, which is part of what's breaking the code in your example. In your code, `names(x)` will get the names of the columns within x, rather than the name of x as it is inside of mylist, which is what you want.

```
x <- data.frame(acolumn = rnorm(10))
q<- data.frame(acolumn = rnorm(10))

mylist <- list(a = x,b = q)


for(i in seq_along(mylist) ){
  filename <- paste(names(mylist[i]),'-myFile.pdf', sep = "")
  pdf(filename)
  plot(myList[[i]]$acolumn)
  dev.off()
}
```